# Excel VBA find first value row in range

Tags: vba, excel

I have this range it selects all values in that column:

`Set c = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SplitSkillInterv").Range("C3:C" & Rows.Count)`

Now I need to make it to find some value and then its row (it could be 1 or 10+, so I need to find first one) any ideas?

I need to find for example: in range c values are from 1 to 10 and randomly repeating till total 100 rows. I and lets say i need to find when first time will be number 3 in range and its row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also a bit unclear what you're asking, but using `Find` might do the trick for you:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SplitSkillInterv")
  Set Rng = .Range("C3:C" & RowCount).Find(What:=".", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, _
             MatchCase:=False)    'find the first "." in the first row
  While Not Rng Is Nothing
    'Your stuff here 
    Set Rng = .Range("C3:C" & RowCount).Find(What:=".", LookIn:=xlValues, _
               lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)  'find the next "."
  Wend
End With
```

I would define `RowCount` prior to entering this code segment. Replace `What:="."` with whatever it is you're looking for.

`Rng` will then be the cell that contains whatever you're searching for. You can do your stuff to that cell at `'Your stuff here`, then the next line will find the next occurrence of your search item. If you only need to do something with the first item, eliminate the rows of code after `Set Rng = ...`

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear to me but they way I understand it this would get you the row number of the first row with the value you want to find, if you replace 'Something' with the value you want to find.

```
i = 3
ValueToFind = 'Something'

Do Until ValueToFind = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SplitSkillInterv").Cells(i, 3).Value
    i = i + 1
Loop
FirstRowWithValue = i
```